# Camel - Advice with issue

Tags: junit, apache-camel

I want to create a JUNIT test that, for the route that performs the database search, point to my mock database search.

Both searches are defined as endpoints:

```
<endpoint id="select-info" uri="sql:{select ...}"/>
<endpoint id="mock-select-info" uri="sql:{select ...}"/>
```

Currently, the only way I can achieve that is changing the route to use the mock endpoint, but that is definitely not ideal. I've seen in the code other JUNIT tests using adviceWith (so it is not a camel release issue, as I've seen in other posts), but I might be understanding it wrong, as I am not succeeding in its use.

So, suppose the route is like below:

```
<route id="request-route" ...>

            <from uri="direct:request-handler" /> 

            <to ref="select-info" />
</route>
```

I created my Junit using the code:

```
@Test
    public void testEntireRouteWithMockSelect() throws Exception {

        context.getRouteDefinition(ORCHESTRATION_ROUTE_ID).adviceWith(context,
                new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                    @Override
                    public void configure() throws Exception {
                        weaveById("select-info").replace().to("mock-select-info");


                    }
                });

        context.setTracing(true);
        context.start();   

        //response validation and asserts       

    }
```

My understanding in the code above is that during the route execution, instead of using "select-info", it would use "mock-select-info", but the execution fails with the error message as:

```
***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There are no outputs which matches: select-info in the route***
```

Per the explanations received, I understood it is related to using ref instead of id.

But I have no clue on how to change my route . I thought of trying (as per the comments, that is how I understand I can do it):

```
<to ref="select-info" id="select-info"/>
```

But then it will throw a NullPointerException.

I am using Camel 2.15 BTW.

Thank you!

Comment: I would add an ID you are using a reference they are not the same thing. Change `<to ref="select-info" />` to `<to id='toSelectInfo" ref="select-info"/>` then use the ID not the REF to select and advise with.  You are using an weaveById <--- it uses the ID.

Comment: Thank you for your attention on this.
The weaveById is referring to the ID. I don't have a reference, as I created two endpoints for the SQL search (using SQL component), so the "to ref" is actually calling the ID.
I tried a few changes to play around with ref and id but didn't work so far.

Comment: The ref might be referring to an ID but the component in the route has no ID. You can have both a ref and a ID on a component.

Comment: I am not sure how to apply it. 
Note that  <to ref="select-info" /> is pointing to the ID. I cannot create a ref and id for it, as it points to an endpoint, which contains only the ID.
I tried to id='select-info" ref="select-info"/>, which would be the most similar approach to what you are recommending, and I got a null pointer exception during execution. 
Not sure if there might be some additional step in this case that I missed.
Could you please advise?

Comment: I am not sure how to apply it. 
I cannot create a ref and id for the SQL component, as per my understanding, it is configured via an endpoint, which allows only the ID.
Note it is defined as:
<endpoint id="select-info" uri="sql:{select ...}
I tried to change the route to cal it as <to ref="select-info" id='select-info" />, which would be the most similar approach to what you are recommending, and I got a null pointer exception during execution. 
Not sure if there might be some additional step in this case that I missed.
Could you please advise?
Thank you again!

Comment: You can have both an ID and ref. The ref is saying use the endpoint as a template but you still need toassign an ID to it.

Comment: Thank for your explanations. I understood the concept, but I am not being able to apply it.I editted the post to make clearer. This way it makes easy for you to clarify all the code changes required.

Comment: Worked at the same company at the same time... interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing a component creates a new copy of the component. When you are declaring an endpoint you are declaring a template not an actuall endpoint component. Remeber to be an actual endpoint it needs to be in a `<from>` or `<to>` tag.

For example:

```
<endpoint id="select-info" uri="sql:{select ...}"/> <!-- The endpoint ID is used to reference the component-->
```

The ID of this component is `select-info` you use this in the reference when you want to use this endpoint.

For exmaple:

```
<from ref="select-info"> <!--This component does not have an ID. It does not inherit the ID from the endpoint it references -->
```

When you declare it like this:

```
 <to ref="select-info" id="select-info"/>
```

This is incorrect as you have a duplicate ID one for the endpoint template and you are telling camel that the `<to>` endpoint(copy of template) has the same ID. ID's must be unique.

Change the code to this

```
<to id="to-select-info" ref="select-info"/>
```

Notice that the copy of the component which will run now has the ID of `to-select-info`. This is the component that will actually run in the route. When you weaveById and use `select-info` as a value it will not find a component but will find component template. This is why it is a NULL pointer, there is no component called `select-info` only the template called `select-info`

Change your test code to:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
                    weaveById("to-select-info").replace().to("mock-select-info");
```

In the above example I am selecting the endpoint `to-select-info` which can be replaced as it is an actuall component not a template.